# Trapping XSD validation rule violations

Tags: xsd, saxon, xerces

I am developing an XSD (v1.0 although I could switch to 1.1) which will be further annotated by customers to describe specific constraints of their business exchanges. Examples of such additional constraints include `xs:fixed`, `xs:maxLength`, etc. During validation, I need violation of these "supplementary" rules to be treated differently. However, I do not see any standard way to "trap" errors in an XSD so that I can handle them. I can use Xerces or Saxon for validation.

Comment: More information required. What do you mean by 'trap'. Are you writing a program to validate XML documents against these XSDs? If so, what language are you using? If not, then what exactly _are_ you doing?

Comment: I want these violations to be handled separately from a normal "error", and not affect the validity of the schema instance. Essentially to be able to turn errors into warnings or something else, more akin to Schematron's roles.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be seeking two things:

a) the ability to distinguish customer-added facets from the ones that you have added

b) facet validation to be treated as non-fatal

a) is impossible unless your own XSD contains zero facets. I cannot think of any way that the XML processor could know whether a facet was in the original XML, or added by a customer.

b) is offered by some XML processors - look for APIs that allow you to supply your own error handler.

Also, note that 'additional constraints' must be limited to simple type facets *only*. In general it is not possible for a validating XML processor to continue after an unexpected tag, or a tag that repeats too many times/too few times.